# Could Provider-Hosted App be inserted in SharePoint Wiki page?

Tags: provider-hosted-app

### Resolved:

There should be Add-In webpart(Client webpart) also added to project, here is how-to:
https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/master/docs/sp-add-ins/include-an-add-in-part-in-the-provider-hosted-add-in.md

---

I used these examples and was able to deploy Provider-Hosted App example from PnP

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7yK5ZDc8gFY

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0hsjr7S-kM&t=911s

But I don't see my App in "Edit Page" -> "Insert" -> "App Part".
How can I insert it in SharePoint page?

SP version: SharePoint Online

Comment: Is your web-part located in the site collection "Web parts" gallery?

Comment: As I understand It is not a web part, it is provider-hosted app, with special wrapper , 'client web part' (Solution-> Add new item -> Client Web part).